# Java 8 stream condition for null values

Tags: java, java-stream

I am using Java 8 stream

```
executeRequest(requestId).stream()
        .map(d-> (Response) d).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the Response object is like this

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Response {

  String title;
  String id;
}
```

when the responses are null, I am getting an error because it is trying to collect null values in a list, I want to have a condition that when title is null, stream does not continue, or any thing that helps me to handle it

Comment: not quite sure on ur specification, should the thing be skipped or the whole stream be aborted? for former, use `.filter(r -> r.title != null)`. for latter u might want to use `.takeWhile(r -> r.title != null)` or similar.

Comment: @Zabuzard as the r value is an object at first and in map I am converting it to Response, it hasn't a title option to check if it is null or not in the filter

Comment: You can put the filter after the map

Comment: @TimMoore it doesn't recognize the value again

Comment: @Tindona I don’t understand what you mean by that. What doesn’t recognise which value?

Comment: @TimMoore when I use filter after the map, `.filter(r.title)` the title is not recognized for the type of object, it is object type even after the map

Comment: thats also the wrong syntax for a lambda. u have to write `.filter(r -> r.title != null)`. carefully read the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need some think like this:

```
List<Response> response = executeRequest(requestId).stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)                    // filter the object if not null
    .map(Response.class::cast)                   // cast the object
    .filter(r -> Objects.nonNull(r.getTitle()))  // filter by title if not null
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using`.filter()`

Try out this

```
executeRequest(requestId).stream()
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.map(d-> (Response) d)
.filter(resp -> Objects.nonNull(resp.getTitle()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: note that this only ensures that the `Response` object itself is not null. OP asked for the `title` (a field of `Response`) not being null.

Comment: it doesn't work. `executeRequest` is returning a list of objects, the response is not null itself but the parameters inside it may be null, and I want to filter them

Comment: @Tindona Updated lambda